# is_user_logged_in returns false when I access certain pages

Tags: php, theme-development

I'm working on a single page application built with WordPress and Vue.js, I used `add_rewrite_rule` to redirect all sub-pages of `projects/` to `index.php`. Only logged-in users can access the application. If a user isn't logged-in a redirect to `wp-login.php` will be returned.

Here's the code I used in `functions.php` to achieve what I mentioned above:

```
// Redirect users who are not logged-in
add_action('template_redirect', function () {

    // Front end only and allow access to ajax functions
    if (is_admin() || wp_doing_ajax()) {
        return;
    }

    // Redirect all pages to the login page if user isn't logged in
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
    }
});

// Remove all default WP template redirects/lookups
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');

add_action('init', function () {
    // Redirect homepage or all requests that start with /projects to index.php so the Vue app
    // is loaded and 404s aren't thrown
    add_rewrite_rule('^projects((/.*)?)', 'index.php', 'top');
});
```

The issue is whenever I access any sub-page `/projects/page/etc` I do get redirected to `wp-login.php` even though I'm logged in! And the strange thing is this happens only on the production server, development and staging servers all work fine.

I used a `var_dump(is_user_logged_in())` inside the callback of the `template_redirect` action and the result is `false`.

Comment: I tried searching for "wordpress is_user_logged_in returns false" and found this, maybe it applies to you? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/is_user_logged_in-always-returns-false/ , some other good results for that search

Comment: Thank you @mozboz I found out why it didn't work, I previously set the home page to `/projects` then later changed it back to `/`, and this caused an issue with login cookies.